# globbing string containing a dash (-)

Tags: unix

How do I glob for a string that contains a dash (-)?

Let's say I want to find all files that contain two digits surrounded by a '-'.

```
ls -[0-9][0-9]-
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "--", you can tell the command that the options are done, e.g.

```
rc@virtualdeb:/tmp/a$ touch -- -91- -88-
rc@virtualdeb:/tmp/a$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 Feb  8 20:33 -88-
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 Feb  8 20:33 -91-
rc@virtualdeb:/tmp/a$ ls -l -- -*-
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 Feb  8 20:33 -88-
-rw-r--r-- 1 rc rc 0 Feb  8 20:33 -91-
```

Comment: Another common trick is `ls ./-[0-9][0-9]-`; `./` refers to the current directory, but it also "hides" the `-` so it isn't treated specially.